# How to get signals and slots working in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I need to link the `loadReceivedFiles()` signal inside StorageSCP class to the `test()` slot inside MainController.

The following code gave me 3 errors:

```
connect(storageSCPWorker->getStorageSCP, &StorageSCP::loadReceivedFiles, this, &MainController::test);
```

> Error 2   error C2248: 'QObject::QObject' : cannot access private member
>   declared in class 'QObject'   c:\users\310214192\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\Test\Test\storagescp.h  18  1   Test
>
> Error 3   error C2248: 'SCP::SCP' : cannot access private member
>   declared in class 'SCP'   c:\users\310214192\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\Test\Test\storagescp.h  18  1   Test
>
> Error 1   error C3867: 'StorageSCPWorker::getStorageSCP': function call
>   missing argument list; use '&StorageSCPWorker::getStorageSCP' to
>   create a pointer to member    C:\Users\310214192\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Test\Test\maincontroller.cpp    10  1   Test

How can I get this working?

**MainController.cpp:**

```
MainController::MainController()
{
    storageSCPWorkerThread = new QThread();
    storageSCPWorker = new StorageSCPWorker(104, "AE_TEST", 16384, "C:/Test/Received/");
    storageSCPWorker->moveToThread(storageSCPWorkerThread);
    connect(storageSCPWorkerThread, &QThread::started, storageSCPWorker, &StorageSCPWorker::startSCP);
    //connect(storageSCPWorker->getStorageSCP, &StorageSCP::loadReceivedFiles, this, &MainController::test);
    storageSCPWorkerThread->start();
}

void MainController::test()
{
    qDebug() << "HELLO MOTO!!!!";
}
```

**MainController.h:**

```
class MainController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainController();
    ~MainController();
public slots:
    void test();
private:
    QThread* storageSCPWorkerThread;
    StorageSCPWorker* storageSCPWorker;
};
```

**StorageSCPWorker.cpp:**

```
StorageSCP StorageSCPWorker::getStorageSCP()
{
    return storageSCP;
}
```

**StorageSCPWorker.h:**

```
class StorageSCPWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    StorageSCPWorker(int port, const OFString &aeTitle, int maxPduLength, const OFString &outputDirectory);
    ~StorageSCPWorker();
    StorageSCP getStorageSCP();
public slots:
        void startSCP();
private:
    int port;
    OFString aeTitle;
    int maxPduLength;
    OFString outputDirectory;
    StorageSCP storageSCP;
    OFCondition status;
};
```

**StorageSCP.cpp:**

```
void StorageSCP::notifyInstanceStored()
{
    emit loadReceivedFiles();
}
```

**StorageSCP.h:**

```
signals:
    void loadReceivedFiles();
```

Comment: `StorageSCP getStorageSCP();` You return a copy of the member. This is most likely not the behavior you want. Return (const) reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First, `getStorageSCP()` should return a pointer to prevent copying the object
- Second connect takes poiters to `QObject`
- Third, second parameter of connect must be a `signal`. As you have an implementation of `notifyInstanceStored`, it's apparently a `slot`, or a regular function. You meant to connect `loadReceivedFiles()`, to `test()`, not `notifyInstanceStored()` to `test()`.

So:

You need to replace

```
StorageSCP StorageSCPWorker::getStorageSCP()
{
    return storageSCP;
}
```

By

```
StorageSCP* StorageSCPWorker::getStorageSCP()
{
    return &storageSCP;
}
```

And then replace

```
connect(storageSCPWorker->getStorageSCP, &StorageSCP::notifyInstanceStored, this, &MainController::test);
```

by

```
connect(storageSCPWorker->getStorageSCP(), &StorageSCP::loadReceivedFiles, this, &MainController::test);
```

or (the old way, Qt4, but still working in Qt5):

```
connect(storageSCPWorker->getStorageSCP(), SIGNAL(loadReceivedFiles()), this, SLOT(test()));
```

Comment: Good, then you can vote up, accept the answer and move forward ;-)